# AWS No instance visible to run a command

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When I am trying to run a command in AWS, I see there is noinstance. 
I am getting below message:

You do not have any Instances in this region

Please someone tell what I am missing. My instance is of N.Virginia & the same is selected when I am trying to run a command.

Comment: You also need to have the latest version of AWS Ec2Config service running.

Answer (score 1):

please change your region with clicking on Right upper side.

There will be some US-East, US west, Singapore. Check it with changing one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the SSM Agent? Until you do that, the EC2 instances are not available to use the run command:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/ssm-agent.html

> The SSM agent is AWS software that you install on your EC2 instances and servers and VMs in your hybrid environment. The agent processes Run Command requests and configures your machine as specified in the request. For more information, see Installing SSM Agent on Linux (Linux) and Installing SSM Agent on Windows (Windows).